# Internal page hidden dropdown menu from boxes (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to fulfill an odd request that I have not done before. I can’t link to the page in question because it is behind an authentication wall, but this is more of a general question about how to accomplish this.

Here is a screenshot of the part of the mockup that is relevant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Zne.jpg

I’ve got these boxes with their images and titles, etc. lined up in 2 rows like they are in the mockup, but I’m not sure of the best way to go about making this collapsible, hidden menu for the items or the left and right navigations parts on the bottom.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

```
<div id="individuals-full"><h1 style="text-align: center;">We assist    individual clients to find personalized solutions involving:</h1>
<br/>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><div id="finance" class="individual-icons"><img  class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1268" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/finance-visas-01-300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Finance <br/>Visas</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="green-cards" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1270" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/marriage-based-green-cards-01-300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Marriage-Based Green Cards</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="removal-of-conditional-residence" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1273" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/removal-of-conditional-residence-01-300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"></p><h1 style="text-align: center;">Removal of Conditions</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="naturalization" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1271" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/naturalization-and-citizenship-01-300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Naturalization &amp; Citizenship</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="adjustment-of-status" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/adjustment-of-status-01-300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Adjustment of Status</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="waivers" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/waivers-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Waivers</h1>&nbsp;   </div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="consular-processing" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/consular-processing-02-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Consular Processing</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="visas-for-victims" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/visa-for-victims-of-crimes-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Visas for Victims of Crimes</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="special-immigrant-juveniles" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/special-immigrant-juveniles-02-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Special Immigrant Juveniles</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="asylum" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/asylum-01-1.png" alt="" width="220" height="220"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Asylum<br/>&nbsp;  </h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="investment-visas" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/investment-visas-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Investment <br/>Visas</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="daca-icon" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/daca-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="dapa-icon" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/dapa-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Deferred Action for Parental Accountability</h1></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div id="removal-deportation-defense" class="individual-icons"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1261" src="http://cmattayers.com/poarch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/removal-and-deportation-defense-01.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align: center;">Removal &amp; Deportation Defense</h1></div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one-row slider with all of those and a div which is hidden. On click (one of the elements @slider) append data to the div with js.